# WPF MVVM Localization C#, runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, localization

I am MVVM WPF begginer so I am searching lightest and easiest possible WPF MVVM localization solution which will also working at **runtime** - change when program is running. Condition is that I cannot user any nuget (or similar) - so **just my code**.

I found several not bad examples on google:
[link 1](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/building-multilingual-mvvm-app.html)
[link 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95449/Localization-and-Complex-Validation-in-MVVM)

If have somebody something else, please for a link. I am searchig solution where I can **later add language without changing the code** - so adding Resources.xx.resx later in to folder.

If any questions please ask. Sorry is question have no meaning. I am searching for any experience from users any already reachable solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of achieving this, however one of my favourites is using a `ResourceDictionary` to declare language resources, this is of course, for the UI only.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    ...

    <System:String x:Key="Test">Hello World</System:String>

    ...

</ResourceDictionary>
```

The trick here is to use **multiple** resource dictionaries for each language, so you may have another one which is for **French**.

```
<System:String x:Key="Test">Bonjour le monde</System:String>
```

Note that the `x:Key` attributes are both the same, this will allow you to make use of `MergedDictionaries` to change the resource reference at runtime.

Anyway, here's an example of it's usage:

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource Test}" ... />
```

You must then use `MergedDictionaries` in your `App.xaml` file and then remove/add the appropriate language when it's needed. For more information on how to do that, see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx).

Also, don't forget that some languages prefer their controls to be **Right to Left**. Arabic is a good example. In this case, I would recommend that you declare a resource for this too, like this:

```
<FlowDirection x:Key="FlowDirection">RightToLeft</FlowDirection>
```

Your windows can then reference this resource like this:

```
<Window ...
    FlowDirection="{DynamicResource FlowDirection}">
```

Like I said, there are other ways of achieving localization, you should certainly check out the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965328.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I use a [custom mark-up extension](http://www.wpftutorial.net/localizemarkupextension.html) with a [custom namespace](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and) which allows me to write XAML like this:

```
<Label Content="{Translate 'First Name:'}" />
```

I also have a utility that pulls all occurrences of these bindings from my XAML and puts it into a spreadsheet for the translators, and another to convert the translations into an XML file. The XML for each language then gets added to a language pack which is a [MEF plugin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx); each file is added to a custom ResourceDictionary that has been decorated with the `[Export]` attribute which allows us to ship updated and/or new language packs after the application has been released.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm interested in your solution. Do you have some kind of example how you have solved this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I preffer [WPF Localization Using RESX Files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files). It supports xaml localization and can be easily used in code-behind, including viewmodels. Resx files are standart solution for WinForms, and WPF Infralution allows to use it in wfp simply too.

just write:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string MyString
    {
        get { return Resources.myString; }
    }
}
```

And it will return you string in accord with your current CultureInfo. If localization file was not found or there is no such resource, the default resx file will be used.

Hope, it helps

Comment: How would you use it in viewmodel?